# Installed windows 8 and it replaced BURG bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, burg

Hey guys I was using Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.10 and not installed windows 8 on the same partition as windows 7. But its replared my BURG bootloader and now its just loading windows 8.

So what can I do to get my BURG bootloader back?

What I have tried till now:

1. Searched a lot on AskUbuntu but didnt get my solution.
2. Booted in with Ubuntu 12.10 live USB and tried **sudo update-grub** but it gave me an error `/usr/sbin/update-grub: 3: exec: grub-mkconfig: Input/output error`

So guys tell me what I can do to get back my BURG bootloader...

Yeah I was using BURG back not GRUB...But right now even GRUB will do.

Thanks